# How is CRA "on your network" configured by default?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

[Create react app](https://create-react-app.dev) (CRA) development build is served on localhost:3000 and sometimes "On your network". By default how does CRA determine what IP address to assign itself on LAN?

PS: I know that HOST and PORT can be configured in the apps .env file. I am curious where to see the default configuration of CRA on LAN.

Comment: It depends on the IP address you're set up with. Being on Linux Mint here, if I run "ifconfig" and see my inet address, that's what is used.

Comment: I dont understand. It serves on 3000 by default and any computer requesting that port on LAN will get a response (firewall willing), it doesn't really dictate its IP, it just binds to a port. Am I misunderstanding your question?